# MatLab - Gaussian elimination with scaled row pivoting

Tags: matlab, matrix, factorization

I am trying to write a function which performs Gaussian elimination with scaled row pivoting.  I almost have it right, but my answer is not quite correct, so something must be wrong in my code.  I have written:

```
function [B,h] = factorization(A)
n = length(A);
p = zeros(1,n);
s = zeros(1,n);
for i = 1:n
    p(i) = i;
    s(i) = max(abs(A(i,1:n)));
end
for k = 1:(n-1)
    m = abs(A(k:n,k));
    q = length(m);
    v = zeros(1,q);
    w = s(k:n);
    for j = 1:q
        v(j) = m(j)/(w(j));
    end
    [pivot,pivot] = max(abs(v(1:end)));
    if pivot ~= 1
        var = p(k);
        p(k) = p(pivot);
        p(pivot) = var;
    end
    for i = (k+1):n
        z = A(p(i),k)/A(p(k),k);
        A(p(i),k) = z;
        for j = (k+1):n
            A(p(i),j) = A(p(i),j) - z*A(p(k),j);
        end
    end
end
B = A;
h = p;
```

Say then that I use the matrix `A = [2 3 -6; 1 -6 8; 3 -2 1]` as input.  My code gives me the output:  `B = [0.6667 -0.8125 -0.4375; 0.3333 -5.3333 7.6667; 3 -2 1], h = [3 2 1]`.  The correct answer, however, should be:  `B = [0.0007 4.3333 -6.6667; 0.3333 -1.2308 -0.5385; 3 -2 1], h = [3 1 2]`

I can't see where in the code I'm doing wrong, so if anyone could help me out, I would be very grateful!